# AWS redis server config for django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-channels

I am following [this](https://medium.com/@elspanishgeek/how-to-deploy-django-channels-2-x-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-8621771d4ff0) tutorial and I am confused with the following code:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
    'CONFIG': {
        "hosts": [(<REDIS ELASTICACHE HOSTNAME>, 6379)],
    },
},
}
```

here, what 'REDIS ELASTICACHE HOSTNAME' refers to?
I created redis instance using AWS ElastiCache, I didn't find 'HOSTNAME' anywhere in the AWS console of redis instance.

I tried to replace it with the name of the instance but after testing it in the shell, I was unable to send message over the layer. The error in testing the layers was:

```
 File "C:\Users\Nouman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 748, in 
 getaddrinfo
 for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
 socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Can any body help?

Comment: The hostname should be an IP or a domain name, so that a TCP connection can be established, though I'm familiar with AWS Redis. I guess you can find out the IP somewhere in AWS.

Comment: I am searching for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I marked the endpoint you need to use instead of 'REDIS ELASTICACHE HOSTNAME' but you need to remove the port and colon just use the endpoint to .com

Example: `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.cache.amazonaws.com`

[image]

Comment: Sorry I thought the other way around. Anyways I tried the endpoint but then it timesout with the following error:
raise OSError(err, f'Connect call failed {address}')
TimeoutError: [Errno 10060] Connect call failed (xxx.xx.xx.xxx, 6379) @fady Alfred

Comment: Because of the Elasticache service always be locked to its VPC and can't connect to it from outside this VPC

Comment: how would I know that It is fixed, because there are still other issues which I am not being able to find out yet. Is there any way to test that the mentioned channels layer config is correct?

Comment: I read an article today says since 2018 you could access it from outside the  VPC but I didn't try it to be honest. try it you can read this and try and inform me if it works.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/accessing-elasticache.html#access-from-outside-aws

Comment: I found it. You have to ssh into your eb environment, and from there certain commands has to be entered to open django shell. Check this:
http://www.kloudwise.com/?qa=5696/run-manage-py-from-aws-eb-linux-instance

Comment: I'm glad you managed to solve it and thank you for sharing the solution